# How to find out when one object is under another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two objects and one above the other, I want to use the condition to check whether one object is under the other, but for some reason nothing works.
I think this is because the interval between object movements is too large and the code simply does not have time to work on time
[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fIDL.png)

```
if (this.transform.position.x == CarPlayer.transform.position.x)
{
    print("isPosition");
}
```

Comment: This will work only if the position is EXACTLY the same.

Comment: MechCollider have some interesting event. Is the element rigid?

Comment: define "under"  you would normally use line/box cast

Comment: Side note when making these checks do it in the `FixedUpdate` to check on Physics frames not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Tolerance Rectangle.
Like

```
 const int tolerance = 3;
 var r = new Rectangle(transform.Position.X-tolerance, transform.Position.Y-tolerance, 2*tolerance, 2*tolerance);
 if (r.Contains(CarPlayer.transform.position.x))
 {
    print("isPosition");
 }
```

You can adapt tolerance to your needs.

Comment: Sorry , but it not work  The type or namespace name 'Rectangle' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `using System.Drawing;`

Comment: Rather than using `System.Drawing` use `UnityEngine.Rect`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use the `Vector3.Distance()` method which returns a float value of the distance between the two GameObject's transforms. If they are on top of one another, the returned value should be 0.

This way you can easily establish the maximum distance to trigger the "isPosition" condition.

```
 float maxDistance = 0.1f;

if (Vector3.Distance(objA.transform.position, objB.transform.position) <= maxDistance)
{
    print("isPosition");
}
```

Comment: He indicated his objects and gives an error (36,57): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'float' to 'UnityEngine.Vector3'

Comment: @LegalPro I'm sorry what? This piece of code cannot give you a type conversion error, make sure you replace "objA" with "this" and "objB" with "CarPlayer"

Comment: This doesn't detect "under", it detects "near"

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((int) this.transform.position.x == (int)CarPlayer.transform.position.x)
{
    print("isPosition");
    RandomPref = rndPref.Next(0, 2);
    Instantiate(PrefabsOil[RandomPref], PositionOilDisgarge.position, PositionOilDisgarge.rotation);
}
```

Comment: This won't work in all cases. Imagine that your car is at `3.1` along the X axis and your other thing is at `2.9`. That's only 0.2 units of distance, but your code will return `false`.